# creating a pop up window for oauth

Tags: javascript, css, authentication, oauth, popup

i'm creating a popup window for oauth. right now, i'm simply using:

```
window.open(href, '', 'chrome=yes')
```

this works pretty well. i'm looking for an improved experience, much like what facebook offers with their login, where:

- the window has a `max-height` and `max-width`. right now, it's the same size as the parent window.
- the window is centered in relation to the parent window. when i follow the instructions on http://www.webpop.com/blog/2011/02/16/add-a-custom-twitter-button-to-your-website, the window is located based on the user's desktop, not the parent window. this messes things up when the browser is not at the top left position or on a different monitor.
- the window closes when the user closes the parent window

however, looking through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open did not help me with this problem. what can i do?

Answer (score 1):

I had faced same issue earlier. This is what I have done:

(1). Use something like this : window.open(SITE_URL+'linkedin/signuplink.php','name','height=500,width=400');

For (2) and (3), I closed popup window as soon as I get a response from oauth.

Looking for better solutions myself.